# Flickering button in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface, flicker

I am making a BCI interface, where the buttons must flicker at specific frequencies, at the moment I am using the ***System.Windows.Timer***, however this is not very precise, and the flickering is not the frequency specified. The class I have used to make the flickering buttons are:

```
StateWithColor[] colors = new StateWithColor[] {
        new StateWithColor(0, Color.Black),
        new StateWithColor(1, Color.White)
    };

public class FlickTimer<T> : IDisposable
      where T : Control
{
    public T Target { get; set; }

    protected readonly IList<StateWithColor> possibleStates = new          List<StateWithColor>();
    protected int currentState = 0;
    //protected int currentState_2 = 1;
    protected object lockState = new object();
    protected Timer timer = new Timer();

    protected void Flicker(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Target == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Target.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Target.Invoke(new EventHandler(Flicker), sender, e);
            return;
        }
        lock (lockState)
        {
            Target.BackColor = possibleStates[currentState].Color;
            //int color = currentState + 1;
            //Target.ForeColor = possibleStates[currentState_2].Color;
            currentState++;
            //currentState_2--;
            if (currentState >= possibleStates.Count)
            {
                currentState = 0;
                //currentState_2 = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public FlickTimer(StateWithColor[] states, int timeout = 0, T target = null)
    {
        Target = target;
        lock (lockState)
        {
            foreach (var state in states)
            {
                possibleStates.Add(state);
            }
        }
        timer.Interval = timeout;
        timer.Tick += Flicker;
        Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
            Stop();
            timer.Tick -= Flicker;
            timer = null;
        }
    }
}

public struct StateWithColor
{    public int State;
    public Color Color;

    public StateWithColor(int state, Color color)
    {
        Color = color;
        State = state;
    }
}
```

This does not give the frequency I have specified when I run the Interface. The screen used for the interface is set to 120HZ, and the interface contains 9 buttons, which should be at the following frequencies: 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.5. Or nine frequencies with in the span of 6-15HZ. The frequencies can be 6.546 or 6.5 does not matter.

Is there a way to make this, and get a flivkering with the exact frequency?

Comment: This is rather silly, must be a homework assignment.  What you are no doubt were supposed to discover by yourself is that it just doesn't matter how accurate the Timer ticks.  You only use it to update the color of the button, not to keep track of time.

Comment: As Hans says, this simply cannot be done using Winforms. The timer classes are all based on timing mechanisms that simply don't have the kind of precision you seem to want. I will note also that on a 120 Hz display, even if you could achieve this kind of precision (e.g. using a lower-level API, like Direct2D), you won't get the effect you want except at frequencies that divide 120 Hz evenly. If "BCI" means "brain-computer interface" (you need to define your terms), and you need a precisely-flickering signal, I think you're going to have to use something other than a computer display.

Comment: It have been done in Silverlight before, but I am supose to do it in a new form for interface, that is why the choise became WinForm. @PeterDuniho

Comment: As I mentioned, it is not physically possible to obtain the level of granularity you state as your goal. Silverlight or otherwise, it isn't plausible that "it has been done". If you are basing research on the incorrect assumption that you or someone else successfully generated these frequencies of updates to some visual indicator (i.e. "flickering"), that research is flawed.